# 400 bad request error while calling ejabberd api

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I am getting 400 bad request error while calling "/api/get_roster" endpoint of ejabberd. I had kept "get_roster" in the scope while requesting the oauth token.

[400 bad request error in ejabberd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8rHq.png)

I guess there is some issue with the permissions. Here is my configuration file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/his89bx39qhvr1h/ejabberd2.yml?dl=0

I have tried to follow the official documentation. As per the API permission guide, I have also tried adding following properties:

```
api_permissions:
  - "Admin access":
    - who:
      - admin
    - what
      - "\*"
      - "!stop"
```

But there was no change. I have following questions:

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. What are possible scopes?

Comment: As per document, Note:: To use get_roster scope, you need to have mod_admin_extra enabled. Otherwise, the command is unknown and you will get an invalid_scope error.

Comment: I have mentioned mod_admin_extra in the modules section of yml file. I did not get invalid_scope error. I am able to acquire token. It is just that when I use that token in POST call to API Endpoint, it says 400 bad request.

Comment: What version of ejabberd you are using?

Comment: I am using  ejabberd 16.01.

Answer (score 0):

Your request should contain Authorization header as below:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <Oauth_token>" http://localhost:5280/api/get_roster -d '[]'
```

Comment: I am doing the same: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgh88lua0jdytu5/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-11%20at%209.24.13%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrlw2gc6p15e5dx/ejabberd_error_log_11_april.log?dl=0. it is not recognising "api_permissions" property. I have misplaced it?

Comment: From logs , it seems that, oauth module is not started correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1190) for more details. If you are accessing as admin you can use `commands_admin_access` rule to provide access to api commands and specify the commands you want to access as follows:

```
commands:
  - add_commands:
    - get_roster
commands_admin_access: configure
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using very old version of Ejabberd. Latest is 17.04 which has lots of changes in API permission framework from 16.01 . api_permission related configuration came in 16.12 version. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784221/accessing-ejabberd-rest-api-through-node-js-app/) for more detail.